# How to Expand & Show Jquery Collapsible Menu Items in a Different Section of the Webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to click on a button, which is denominated with `id="firstclick"` in the code below, and have a collapsible expanding right below in the second section. The second section is named `id="number_two"`. The collapsible is not allowed to expand within its own section (`id="number_one"`).

Since the collapsible expands in a different section, the style of section with `id="number_one"`, may not be applicable to section with `id="number_two"` (where it has expanded).

How to realize this task and how to style the expanded part appropriately?

I am using `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>` for the collapsible.

```
<body>

<section id="number_one">

<div id="first_collapsible" class="without_icon" data-role="collapsible">
        <h1> 
            <a id="firstclick" href="#">
            <div class="pakket makesquare">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="heading-2"><p>Product</p></div>
                    <div class="textprices derde">          
                    <p>Credits</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </a>
        </h1>

        <div id="first_collapsible_sub" data-role="collapsibleset">

                <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
                    <h1><li class="odd"><span class="titlecollapsible"><a href="#">Specifications</a></span></li></h1>

                    <div data-role="collapsibleset">

                        <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right"><h1><li class="odd"><span class="pricing_no"><a href="#">Size</a></span></li></h1><p class="uitleg_pakket">Not too big</p></div>

                        <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right"><h1><li class="odd"><span class="pricing_no"><a href="#">weight</a></span></li></h1><p class="uitleg_pakket">Not too heavy</p></div>

                        <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right"><h1><li class="odd"><span class="pricing_no"><a href="#">color</a></span></li></h1><p class="uitleg_pakket">Light</p></div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <a class="button-standard hoofdscherm" href="#">Close collapsible</a>
                <a class="button-standard" href="#">Proceed >></a>

        </div>

</div>


</section>



<section id="number_two">

<!-- I would like to have the "collapsible" from section with id="number_one" to expand in this section. The collapsible within id="number_one" should not expand. -->

</section>



</body>
</html>
```